# sqoop import from DB2 to Datastax, schema not in proper format

Tags: db2, sqoop, datastax-enterprise

When I try to sqoop `import` (Datastax 3.2.0) from DB2 database using the below command:

`./dse sqoop import --connect jdbc:db2://172.29.252.40:4922/DSNN --username tst -P --table tstschema."dsn_filter_table" --cassandra-keyspace SqoopTest --cassandra-column-family actest2 --cassandra-row-key PREDNO --cassandra-thrift-host 10.247.31.42 --cassandra-create-schema --split-by PREDNO`

`[ DB2 Select query: select * from SchemaName.TableName with ur; ]`

Why I am not getting the schema in proper format as it is in DB2?

Issue Faced:
Why **Column Names** of DB2 table are getting **into rows** of Cassandra?

Request your help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the Datastax version of Sqoop, but generally the parameter --table can't be used to also specify a schema name. You can specify the schema in the JDBC URL using currentSchema property. For example

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:db2://host/db:currentSchema=tstschema
```